# fportfolio group constraint do not work

Tags: r, constraints

Recently I use fPortfolio in R:

```
group.1 = c("minsumW[ sec1 ] = 0.215688 " ,  "maxsumW[ sec1 ] = 0.3126 " )
  groupConstraints = c(group.1)
  portfolioConstraints(ret, mv, groupConstraints)
```

if I set like above, it worked well.

But if I set constraint number from matrix:

```
group.1 = c("minsumW[ sec1 ] = lobound[1]" ,  "maxsumW[ sec1 ] = 0.3126 " )
  groupConstraints = c(group.1)
  portfolioConstraints(ret, mv, groupConstraints)
```

it does not worked.

Warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try

c(paste("minsumW[ sec1 ] = ",lobound[1],sep=""),"maxsumW[ sec1 ] = 0.3126 ")